# In Rust is there a way for me to define two structs, where both will follow a standard struct?

Tags: rust, struct

I'm trying to create a struct that will contain basic functions present in all other structs, here:

```rust
pub struct GenericSelect {
    table: String,
    distinct: bool,
    columns: Option<String>,
    group: Option<String>,
    order: Option<String>,
    limit: Option<u32>,
    offset: Option<u32>,
}

impl GenericSelect {
    pub fn new<T: Into<String>>(table: T) -> GenericSelect {
        GenericSelect {
            table: table.into(),
            distinct: false,
            columns: None,
            group: None,
            order: None,
            limit: None,
            offset: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn distinct(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        self.distinct = true;
        self
    }

    pub fn columns<T: Into<String>>(&mut self, columns: T) -> &mut Self {
        self.columns = Some(columns.into());
        self
    }

    pub fn group<T: Into<String>>(&mut self, group: T) -> &mut Self {
        self.group = Some(group.into());
        self
    }

    pub fn order<T: Into<String>>(&mut self, order: T) -> &mut Self {
        self.order = Some(order.into());
        self
    }

    pub fn limit(&mut self, limit: u32) -> &mut Self {
        self.limit = Some(limit);
        self
    }

    pub fn offset(&mut self, offset: u32) -> &mut Self {
        self.offset = Some(offset);
        self
    }

    pub fn build(&self) -> String {
        let mut statement = String::from("SELECT");

        if self.distinct {
            statement.push_str(" DISTINCT");
        }

        if let Some(columns) = &self.columns {
            statement.push_str(&format!(" {}", columns));
        } else {
            statement.push_str(" *");
        }

        statement.push_str(&format!(" FROM {}", self.table));

        if let Some(group) = &self.group {
            statement.push_str(&format!(" GROUP BY {}", group));
        }

        if let Some(order) = &self.order {
            statement.push_str(&format!(" ORDER BY {}", order));
        }

        if let Some(limit) = &self.limit {
            statement.push_str(&format!(" LIMIT {}", limit));
        }

        if let Some(offset) = &self.offset {
            statement.push_str(&format!(" OFFSET {}", offset));
        }

        statement.push(';');
        statement
    }
}
```

And I want a specific struct to have everything that this one has, without needing to write method by method, and I also want to have the possibility of implementing a function if necessary, like changing the behavior of a specific function, etc.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use traits, no?

Comment: Yes read up on traits

Comment: yeah, but how a trait can update a property from struct, do you have an example? i dont find one

Comment: Read about the default implementation of a trait in the rust book here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html It gives examples

Comment: When the methods themselves have to refer to the structs' properties, then you have to define trait bounds on the type that the generic methods refer to. I.e. if a method updates an attribute `distinct` then you have to ensure the type has that attribute. Rust cannot assume that any struct has that attribute and the complier will complain about it if you try.

Comment: Rust favors composition over inheritance. So create a struct with all shared functionality you want, and include it as a field in the "extended" structs.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman like this? struct foo { base: GenericSelect }

Comment: Yes, exactly. And forward methods.

Comment: With a trait-based approach, consider https://docs.rs/delegate/latest/delegate/ or https://docs.rs/ambassador/latest/ambassador/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traits will do exactly what you're looking for.

Here's the example from the Rust docs:

```rust
pub trait Summary {
    fn summarize_author(&self) -> String;

    fn summarize(&self) -> String {
        format!("(Read more from {}...)", self.summarize_author())
    }
}
```

This is your template that describes shared behavior. When you'd like a struct to participate in this shared behavior, write an impl on it, writing at least the required functionality

```rust
impl Summary for Tweet {
    fn summarize_author(&self) -> String {
        format!("@{}", self.username)
    }
}
```

In the trait, you can have functions with default implementations `summarize`. Then, specify functions like `summarize_author` that give you some standard interface across structs for your default implementations to rely on.

If you wanted to override the summarize function, you could do that in the `impl`:

```rust
impl Summary for Tweet {
    fn summarize_author(&self) -> String {
        format!("@{}", self.username)
    }

    fn summarize(&self) -> String {
        format!("(More about this tweet by {})...", self.summarize_author())
    }
}
```

Source: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html

Comment: I know this is sample code from the book, but to be clear, neither method should return `String`. They should return a `Display`-implementing type that borrows `self`. Taken verbatim, these examples will cause several unnecessary heap allocations.

Comment: Valid point! Let's keep things simple for folks new to the language learning about traits though. The more we can do to flatten out our learning curve, the more welcoming we can be to new users!

Answer (score 0):

Go study up in `traits` and `impl`.
Rust doesn't allow for `struct` inheritance, but you can gain some ground using `impl` and `traits` like so:

```
trait Hello {
    fn speak(&self);
}

struct Dog {
    name: String,
}

struct Cat {
    name: String,
}

impl Hello for Dog {
    fn speak(&self) {
        println!("{} says: Woof!", self.name);
    }
}

impl Hello for Cat {
    fn speak(&self) {
        println!("{} says: Meow!", self.name);
    }
}

trait BigDogTrick {
    fn trick(&self); 
}
trait SmallDogTrick {
    fn trick(&self);
}

impl BigDogTrick for Dog {
    fn trick(&self) {
        println!("big bark");
        
    }
}

impl SmallDogTrick for Dog {
    fn trick(&self) {
        println!("small bark");
    }
}


// Example usage of the structs and trait
fn main() {
    let dog = Dog {
        name: String::from("Buddy"),
    };

    let cat = Cat {
        name: String::from("Whiskers"),
    };

    dog.speak(); // prints "Buddy says: Woof!"
    cat.speak(); // prints "Whiskers says: Meow!"
    
    BigDogTrick::trick(&dog); // prints "big bark"
    SmallDogTrick::trick(&dog); // prints "small bark"
}
```